# MySQL grouping different rows to create group and simple products

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, grouping

I am migrating products from one system to Magento and there is a group/child products relation in an old system and I have to maintain in the Magento System

**The current table structure I have:**

```
[id],   [sku],  [name],         [parent id]
202182 |240330 |parent product |
202183 |240331 |child product 1|[202182][Parent-Product-240330]
202184 |240332 |child product 2|[202182][Parent-Product-240330]
```

**What i want to achieve:**

```
[id],   [sku],   [name],         [product_type], [associated_sku]
202182 |240330 | parent product |grouped        |240331=0.0000,240332=0.0000
202183 |240331 | child product 1|simple         |
202184 |240332 | child product 2|simple         |
```

Can you please help me to write a query to achieve it.

Comment: Does the hierachy have only two levels, or it can have many more?

Comment: What version of MySQL (or MariaDB)? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @TheImpaler I am using MySQL 5.6 and this hierarchy has multiple levels, i have put 2 levels is just for example

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL 5.x does not implement "Recursive CTEs". If you were using MySQL 8.x I would write a query that produces your result. In MySQL 5.6 you'll need to assemble the data in your application (much more programming).

Comment: Alternatively, if somehow you could export/import your current data into a MySQL 8.x database, I/we could help you easily.

Comment: @TheImpaler I can try to import database to version 8 and run this query. but can you please send me the query to achieve it

Comment: Let me see, does the hierarchy always have a maximum of two levels (like in your example), or can it have many more (grandchildren, great-grandchildren)?

Comment: @TheImpaler it only has 2 levels

Answer (score 1):

If the hierarchy has only two levels, it's perfectly possible to do it in MySQL 5.6, so you are good as you are (if it had a variable number of levels you would need MySQL 8.x).

The query I would use is:

```
select 
  p.id,
  p.sku,
  p.name,
  'grouped' as product_type,
  group_concat (concat(c.id, '=0.0000') order by c.id) as associated_sku
from product p
join product c on c.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.sku, p.name
union all
select
  id,
  sku,
  name,
  'simple' as product_type,
  null as associated_sku
from product
where parent_id is not null
```

**Note**: This query assumes the value of `parent_id` is null on parent rows.

Comment: Thankyou for your query and it looks perfect but it didnt run successfully as in join, i have to match this data c.parent_id ([202182][Parent-Product-240330]) = p.id(202182) which didnt work as i need to write LIKE in the query for example: c.parent_id like concat('%',p.id,'%') but i didnt get anything not too sure if my Like statement is wrong.

Comment: That join condition looks fine. I don't know why it doesn't match rows. The following query (just tried it) is similar: `select '[202182][Parent-Product-240330]' like concat('%', '202182', '%')`. It does work, since it returns `1` (aka "true"). I recommend you run the query by parts to debug it; maybe you can rung the first half only, and see what it finds.

Comment: is there any way i can run this script in different pieces? because i am running it in both PHPMyAdmin and SSH and it is taking huge times like hours and hours and then throws error that system time out i event tried putting Limit 1000 but it still did the same.

Comment: Well.. you can run the first section (before the `UNION ALL`) and see what you get. Then you can run the second (after the `UNION ALL`). The result should both queries combined.